# Laravel: Hooking up a service

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

So I've implemented a service structure that a stackoverflow user suggested to me in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551363/where-should-i-put-this-code-in-laravel/23551522#answer-23551522). I've got it mostly working but I'm running into the error:

```
Class 'App\Services\Mailer\Facades\Mailer' not found
```

My service folder structure looks like this:

```
app
|   App
|   |   Services
|   |   |   Mailer
|   |   |   |   Mailer.php
|   |   |   |   MailerFacade.php
|   |   |   |   MailerServiceProvider.php
```

Each of the files in the Mailer directory are namespaced as:

```
<?php namespace App\Services\Mailer;
```

Except for the Facade which is namespaced as the following per the example in [this blog](http://fideloper.com/create-facade-laravel-4):

```
<?php namespace App\Services\Mailer\Facades;
```

I put a test method in my `Mailer.php` file's `Mailer` class:

```
<?php namespace App\Services\Mailer;
//base service class

class Mailer {

  public function sayHi(){
    return "hello!";
  }      
}
```

I then created the facade:

```
<?php namespace App\Services\Mailer\Facades; 
// Facade for Mailer

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Mailer extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor(){ return 'mailer'; }
}
```

Then I created the Service Provider to hook them all together:

```
<?php namespace App\Services\Mailer;
// Mailer's service provider

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MailerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function register(){

        $this->app['mailer'] = $this->app->share( function ($app){
            return new App\Services\Mailer\Mailer;
        });

        $this->app->booting( function (){
            $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
            $loader->alias('Mailer', 'App\Services\Mailer\Facades\Mailer');
        });
    }
}
```

THe loader for the facade is pointing to the correct namespace, `'App\Services\Mailer\Facades\Mailer'`, but when I try calling the method in one of my controllers like so:

```
public function showMe(){
    return Mailer::sayHi();
}
```

I get the message I noted at the top.

I tried putting the facade into a subfolder of the `Mailer` directory called `Facade` so that the namespace and folder structure matched exactly, but I got the same error.

I read and re-read the example, the original stackoverflow post, the composer documentation on `psr-4` to make sure I wasn't referencing anything incorrectly, and I can't seem to figure it out.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**

So I took a step back and created a vanilla laravel project and tried to add in a service the same way I'm trying in my main project. It's running into a similar error.

Here's a screen shot of every file involved:

[image]

Process:

- I created my new laravel project
- I created my `App/Services/Greetings` directory structure
- I added my psr-4 load path to my `composer.json` file
- I created my underlying class `Greetings`
- I Created a `GreetingsFacade` class that returns the string 'greetings' for the `getFacadeAccessor method
- I created a Greetings Service Provider class `GreetingsServiceProvider` and added
  the register method with it's commands
- I added my service provider to the app/config/app.php file in the providers array
  [image]
- I added a route that returns a closure that uses my new `Greetings` service
- I then ran `composer dump-autoload` and loaded my route

When I load my page I get the error "Class 'App\Services\Greetings\App\Services\Greetings\Greetings' not found" :(

Comment: Does your namespace show in the `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`?

Comment: Yes, it shows up as `'App\\' => array($baseDir . '/app/App'),`

Comment: Is this error at line 9 of your service provider?

Comment: Yes, and line nine is `return new App\Services\Greetings\Greetings;`

Comment: Oh god, am I supposed to be returning the underlying class or the facade class on line 9??

Comment: Ah, I switched it out for the facade class and it is giving a similar error. I don't understand why it's doubling the namespace when looking for the class :/

Comment: It's not that. Code looks good to me, you are trying to return a new instance of your service, but PHP cannot find it at that point, wich is very odd. Could you post actual code? I would like to test it here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52404/discussion-between-chris-schmitz-and-antonio-carlos-ribeiro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your directory structure:

```
app
|   App
|   |   Services
|   |   |   Mailer
|   |   |   |   Mailer.php
|   |   |   |   MailerFacade.php
|   |   |   |   MailerServiceProvider.php
```

Your classes namespaces must be:

Service

```
<?php namespace App\Services\Mailer; 

class Mailer {}
```

Service Provider

```
<?php namespace App\Services\Mailer; 

class MailerServiceProvider {}
```

Facade

```
<?php namespace App\Services\Mailer; 

class MailerFacade {}
```

And you autoloader:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/App"
    },
},
```

For it to work the way you are trying to do, your directory structure would have to be

```
app
|   App
|   |   Services
|   |   |   Mailer
|   |   |   ├── Facades
|   |   |   |   └── Facade.php
|   |   |   |   Mailer.php
|   |   |   |   MailerServiceProvider.php
```

EDIT:

In your Greetings namespace, change from:

```
return new App\Services\Greetings\Greetings;
```

to

```
return new Greetings;
```

And it should work because they are in the same namespace. For an easy reading of the code, add

```
use App\Services\Greetings\Greetings;
```

In the top of your .php file.

Comment: :/ That looks like what I have. I'm going to update my post with a screen shot of a vanilla test project that is having the same problem. The screen shot has every file involved shown. If you have a sec to look at it I'd super appreciate it.

Comment: That's not what I currently see in your post you have `<?php namespace App\Services\Mailer\Facades; ` But your tree is `App\Services\Mailer`.

Answer (score 2):

psr-4 expects your directory structure to reflect the namespace structure.

In order to autoload a class `App\Services\Mailer\Facades\Mailer`, it will look for the file `App/Services/Mailer/Facades/Mailer.php`.

Additionally, the facade accessor `mailer` (thus also the IoC-Container slug `mailer`) is already used by `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail`.

Try something different like `my_mailer`:

```
<?php namespace App\Services\Mailer\Facades; 
// Facade for Mailer

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Mailer extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor(){ return 'my_mailer'; }
}
```

and

```
<?php namespace App\Services\Mailer;
// Mailer's service provider

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class MailerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function register(){

        $this->app['my_mailer'] = $this->app->share( function ($app){
            return new App\Services\Mailer\Mailer;
        });

        $this->app->booting( function (){
            $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
            $loader->alias('Mailer', 'App\Services\Mailer\Facades\Mailer');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So change the namespace `App\Services\Mailer\Facades` just by `App\Services\Mailer` and call it like that `App\Services\Mailer\MailerFacade`

Comment: Regardless of which method I try (putting it in a folder and renaming the file or leaving it at the `Mailer` level and changing the namespace) I get the error `Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!`. Does this mean it can't find the class?

Comment: Felix, thanks for your help. Antonio helped me work though the problem in a chat. Your posts helped me understand psr-4 a bit better. When I rolled back my main project and implemented the service from the ground up I was sure to rename the mailer references per your suggestion. Thanks for your help.